# Entity Framework Updating Model with an error

Tags: c#, entity-framework

> ```
> Error 2019: Member Mapping specified is not valid. The type 
>
> 'Edm.String[Nullable=True,DefaultValue=,MaxLength=Max,Unicode=,FixedLength=False
>
> ]' of member 'definition' in type 'rcOA.sysdiagram' is not compatible with 
>
> 'SqlServer.varbinary(max)
>
> [Nullable=True,DefaultValue=,MaxLength=2147483647,FixedLength=False]'
> ```
>
> of member
>
> ```
> 'definition' in type 'rcOA.Store.sysdiagrams'.        
>
> E:\workstation\visual_studio\rcoa\rcOA.Model\rcOA.edmx    1801
> ```

Long time not coding with EF, have no ideas about this.

Comment: The error is pretty clear; you tried to use a `nullable string` in your model, but your server has a `nullable varbinary` defined for that property.

Comment: not sure why you are trying to map the `sysdiagrams` table, though...

Comment: i can build success,but run error. how to fix

Comment: it's a secondhand project.so im not familiar

Comment: don't put a check mark next to `sysdiagrams` when scripting your database.  it doesn't make sense to have a model for that table, and it won't work correctly anyway.

Comment: it's complexity. i try to keep not more change. there are associations in many projects.so i delete this object sysdiagrams,i need to change more,edit more.

Comment: I don't understand.  are you saying others can compile this same code without errors, but you cannot?

Comment: it's not a code error.just given by [VS Error list]. I can build succes.it seems like version problem.But I don't know what

Comment: This still isn't making any sense.  there is no reason at all to ever have a model in C# representing the `sysdiagrams` table.  It just plain won't work.  If you didn't add it, then someone else must have, and they must be experiencing the same issues with the code.